# Convert delegate from C# to VB

Tags: c#, vb.net, delegates

how can I convert the following code from C# to VB without exposing "variable" as global variable.

```
private void SomeMethod(SomeType variable)
{
    this.SomeEvent+= delegate
    {
        if (variable == 1)
        {
           this.DoSomething();
        }
    }
    //here I have some other code
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible solution

```
Private Sub SomeMethod(ByVal variable As Integer)
    AddHandler Me.SomeEvent,
        Sub()
            If (variable = 1) Then
                Me.DoSomething()
            End If
        End Sub
    Console.WriteLine("ciao")
End Sub
```

I just tried that and it works like a charm, so i don't know why u say it doesnt :( Visual studio 2010.

You can also do something like this

```
Private Sub SomeMethod(ByVal variable As Integer)
    Me.SomeEvent = DirectCast(Delegate.Combine(Me.SomeEvent, Sub()
        If (variable = 1) Then
            Me.DoSomething
        End If
    End Sub), MyDelegate)
    ...mycode
End Sub
```

Delegate.Combine have exactly the same effect as AddHandler.

I don't have visual studio 2008 so I don't know how to write that in VS2008, try the second solution, the first seems to work only on 2010.

If this doesn't work you can try this out, more code to write:

```
Public Delegate Sub MyDelegate()

Public Class Class1

    Public Event SomeEvent As MyDelegate

    Private Class MyDelegateClass

        Public Owner As Class1
        Public Variable As Integer

        Public Sub Method()
            If (Variable = 1) Then
                Owner.DoSomething()
            End If
        End Sub

    End Class

    Private Sub SomeMethod(ByVal variable As Integer)

        Dim dc As New MyDelegateClass
        dc.Owner = Me
        dc.Variable = variable

        AddHandler Me.SomeEvent, AddressOf dc.Method
        Console.WriteLine("ciao")
    End Sub

    Public Sub DoSomething()
        Console.WriteLine("hello")
    End Sub

End Class
```

Visual studio syntactic sugar does something like this with anonymous delegate.

Comment: this does not work, since after the first EndSub it cut off my method and the rest of the code is not executed:

Comment: It is not accessible. Once I add End Function VS automatically changes it to End Sub (which kills my method)

Comment: I am using VS2008 and this was the reason why the code was not working. I should have added this information from the beginning.

If you can think of solution for VS2008 I will really appreciate it. Anyway I am marking this as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Google pointed me at this [website](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/) which says they're free.

Comment: Like any automated conversion tool it will have it's errors. You can't rely just on the converter, you should have some knowledge about how keywords differ between the two languages. I don't know VB but I've converted VB code to C# for use just from reading articles on keywords.

Comment: Here is what I use to convert between the two: [VB and C# Comparison](http://www.harding.edu/fmccown/vbnet_csharp_comparison.html)

Comment: I am converting C# to VB quite a lot, but still I can't make it with this delegate.

Comment: @checho Well, Ramhound gave you a link to read about about delegates in VB and Salvatore offered a VB translation for you.

Comment: yep, neither one of them helped.

Comment: Try this page on [Anonymous Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514189.aspx) from the MSDN.

Comment: Since you mentioned here is another useful online converter from Telerik that I use [link](http://converter.telerik.com/)

Comment: @checho - The code you posted is not even valid code so its not a shocked an conversion tool didn't help.  If you cannot do this without a tool then you have bigger problems then we can solve.  It sounds like you simply do not understand delegants